# Running Python code easily for end users in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, update, qgs

I have a basic bit of code that updates layout names to help manage revisioning and PDF names etc.

Currently, it is run from the project Python actions - so it runs whenever the project is saved, this works but has issues and I would like a way of doing it like pressing a button which requires user interaction. I have looked at creating a processing script but that is beyond my skills or poorly documented.

```py
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsPathResolver, QgsExpressionContextUtils) 
from qgis.gui import (QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge)

project = QgsProject.instance()

from datetime import date

today = date.today() # get date
date = today.strftime("%d_%m_%Y") # set and format text string
composerTitle = 'PrintLayout' # Name of the composer
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layouts_list = projectLayoutManager.printLayouts()
BTC_Prj_Number = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project).variable('BTC_Prj_Number') # Get the project number form the project variables
for layout in layouts_list:
    oldname = layout.name()
    findleft = (len(oldname))-10 # find the length of the layout name without the current date
    shortname = oldname[5:findleft] # layout name without the old date
    layoutName = BTC_Prj_Number+shortname+date # layout name with a new date and project number
    layout.setName(layoutName)
```

Comment: I am not certain what your question is. It would be good if you could edit what you have stated  to provide a question. Could you also add if you have you ever tried the Processing toolbox's python menu "Create new script from Template...."? I

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the minimal plugin skeleton in [this repository](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qgis-minimal-plugin). Copy the files (only `metadata` and `__init__` are required) to a new folder in `plugin` folder. Change the files' content as follows:

Folder content:

[image]

**metadata.txt**:

```ini
[general]
name=UpdateLayoutNames
description=description
about=about
version=1.0
qgisMinimumVersion=3.0
author=Your Name
email=email
repository=url
```

****init**.py**:

```py
from os.path import join, dirname

from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsExpressionContextUtils
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon

def classFactory(iface):
    return UpdateLayoutNames(iface)


class UpdateLayoutNames:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        icon = QIcon(join(dirname(__file__), "icon.png"))
        self.action = QAction(icon, 'Update', self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
        del self.action

    def run(self):
        from datetime import date
        today = date.today()
        date = today.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
        composerTitle = 'PrintLayout'

        project = QgsProject.instance()
        projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
        layouts_list = projectLayoutManager.printLayouts()
        BTC_Prj_Number = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project).variable('BTC_Prj_Number')

        for layout in layouts_list:
            oldname = layout.name()
            findleft = (len(oldname)) - 10
            shortname = oldname[5:findleft]
            layoutName = BTC_Prj_Number + shortname + date
            layout.setName(layoutName)
```

You can use this icon (icon.png):

[image]

Plugin toolbar:

[image]

Comment: I had to fix a bug in my original code as the project variable I use needs to be converted to a string but other than that it works perfect!

Comment: A great answer of yours, as usual!